# Marshalling functions with pointer to struct argumants and nested c structs with arrays

Tags: c#, c, struct, interop, marshalling

I want to use a library I wrote in C in a C# form application. Functions with primitive type arguments work just fine. But marshalling structs seem to be a problem.

```
struct Struct1 {
   UINT8 a;
   UINT16 b;
   UINT8 c[8];
}

struct Struct2 {
   UINT16 a;
   struct Struct1 b;
}
```

These 2 will be passe to a function with the following prototype.

```
void func(struct Struct1 * p1,struct Struct2 * p2)
```

I tried couple of examples i found on the internet but couldnt get it to work properly.

Comment: Only real obstacle is the Struct1.c member, it needs [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)].  You might well do something else wrong, but if you don't show us then we can't tell.  No point to that, is there?

Comment: I dont have the code with me right now. But I will try to get it added to the question as soon as possible.

Comment: @HansPassant, and do I have to initialize the array in `Struct1` with `new UINT8[8]` when i marshall it with SizeConst = 8?

Comment: It is impossible to not discover this by yourself when you try it.

Comment: @HansPassant, I cant because i simply dont have the tools to try it by myself right now. If you are not willing to help, but only post witty comments why are you even on this site?